What if PCA is unable to group my samples, but K-means perfectly clusters them? Is there any problem with my data analysis? Is it possible?
I am not an expert, but I am currently using unsupervised methods to better explain my mass spectrometry data obtained via DART-MS analyses. I am still learning.
It turned out that when analyzing my data on the MetaboAnalyst platform, I did not observe differentiation via PCA, while K-means was able to cluster my samples into two distinct groups, which were very coherent with the sample characteristics.
I have already checked the protocol multiple times. It works well when analyzing other samples, by which I mean "PCA in agreement with K-means results, both of them in accordance."
If that is correct, how can we explain this disagreement?
PCA results

K-means result were you can see tha samples Q3,Q4, T2,T3, V3, V4, R3 and R4 are grouped as expected:


How do you use PCA for clustering, exactly? Can you show us an output of the tool you're using for that?

Thank you! I've just edited it to add the images.
I uploaded the spectra and applied sample normalization through the following workflow: 1) normalization sum; 2) scaling the data by 'auto scaling'; 3) no data transformation applied. After trying different approaches, this was the best path I could find to achieve good data normalization.
I got a very nice Gaussian curve, which I interpreted as confirmation that the data had been normalized effectively.
Then, you just need to click on the links to perform the desired analysis. Each analysis uses the normalized data as input.

If it's possible, can you mention what the documentation of your software say about the meaning of the ellipses or how they are calculated?

Note that the question is temporarily closed, but if you edit your question and provide additional details it may be re-opened. The purpose of the closure is to avoid answers that might misleading, due to a lack of possibly essential information in the question.

It's not the job of PCA to identify groups whereas it is the job of k means to do so. What's not clear to me is did you apply k-means to the raw data, all the PCs or just the first two PCs. I note that your first two PCs account for 18.8% of the variation only. It would take a subject-matter expert to say much more about whether this is good for your kind of data and even such an expert would need to be told what your variables were and more about the PCA results. I have to say that it's not clear what you're asking us to say here. Cluster analysis finds clusters, PCA is agnostic about them.

More simply, do you have a hypothesis that there are two distinct groups?
